# Limits on making outbound API calls from Salesforce org

Tags: api, callout, governorlimits

I am wondering if there is any Salesforce system limit regarding the number of outbound (i.e. towards other systems) API calls that can be made from an org. I am aware of all of the concurrent and 24h-rolling limits on inbound API calls, and would like to know if there exists something similar regarding outbound calls or are they not limited by Salesforce?

Comment: You can only do 100 callouts within a single transaction, and there's a maximum timeout of 120 seconds per transaction (all requests combined). Some other limitations apply as well: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API call limit is only for inbound calls. Outbound calls are governed by the per transaction and maximum timeout limits.

Reference:

[Salesforce Developer Limits Quick Reference](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/9/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf)